# Good-styled console input

Tags: python

I'm writing a little Chatserver/-client to learn Python.
Now I want to make the consoleinput a little bit nicer, but I don't know how to do it...

Everytime I recieve a message from the socket, I do `print()` in the listening thread.
But then the text already entered to `input()` is over the printed message and the cursor is at the bottom.

What can I do, that is works like in Minecraft-Server, so the text already entered moves to the bottom?
Would be great if someone can help :)

Comment: You can't have that sort of fine grained control over the console input. You need to write a GUI application instead, and emulate console like functionality but customize it as you need.

Comment: Python has a built-in GUI module called `tkinter`. Take a look at the `Text`, `Entry`, and `Button` widgets to get started. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

Comment: I would use curses for that

Comment: Yeah, but how does it work in minecraft? I think its possible, but I have no idea how

Comment: Note that Minecraft was written in Java, I'm not sure if it still is though.

Comment: I know, but I just wait a bit, maybe someone comes with the perfect answer but yours is not bad too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get that level of control with the console, but you can use python's default tkinter to make a simple UI. Below is an example (Python 3) that I whipped up in a few minutes. You can type in messages, press send, and they will appear in the box above.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def send(view, entry):
    view.insert('1.0', entry.get() + "\n")

root = Tk()

msgview = Text(root, width=100, height=20)
msgview.grid(sticky=(N,E,S,W))

mymessage = StringVar(value="type here...")

msginput = Entry(root, textvariable=mymessage)
msginput.grid(sticky=(E,W))

sendbutton = ttk.Button(root, text="send",\
                        command=lambda: send(msgview, msginput))
sendbutton.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

I suggest looking at the [tkdocs tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/) over the effbot one, since it is clearer, easier to follow and is more thorough in my opinion. New Mexico Tech also provides a great reference for tkinter [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html)

Comment: OMG, never seen a gui with 10 lines of code o.O
whatever.. Isn't it possible to get every character entered and if some text is printed you output \r or \b and append all entered text to the end? A gui I will add later.

Comment: Hmmm... this works: print("Test",end="") print("\rWorks",end="") print("\bing") >Outputs "only" Working. I only need an other way to input...

Comment: You still won't be able to separate the client typing text and text printed. The simplest thing would be to have a separate window for entering text and repeatedly clearing it after each send.